# Parse.com Automatic user

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

When I have a connection to the internet I am able to have the user login automatically. Once I am logged in I am able to turn off my wifi and continue to use the app. The problem that I run into is when I close the app (double tap home button and swipe up on my app) and try to open the back up again I get this error message:

```
"The Internet connection appears to be offline."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.4.0)
2014-09-20 22:20:02.376 LeadOff Dev[4030:5a27] Network connection failed. Making attempt 3       after sleeping for 2.470375 seconds
```

And here's my autologin process from the root view controller:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);

}
else {
    LoginViewController* nextViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Current User logged out");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing the app, Parse has to call home to get started; if the app is running in the background this initialization has already happened and you don't need to run it again - that's why you can reload from the background and run without connectivity after the start.

However, on the first load you **MUST** call `[Parse setApplicationId:appID clientKey:clientKey]` that runs usually in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on your `AppDelegate.m` file. Without this call, you get:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'

**Bottom line: You have to have connectivity when you start an app with Parse.**